# Will mysql lock a range of rows when I select the begin and end rows for update?

Tags: mysql, database, locking

Suppose I have a table which has two column. One is named `id`, and this is its primary key. The other is called `value`. This table has 10 rows as below.

```
1 'A'
2 'B'
3 'C'
4 'D'
5 'E'
6 'F'
7 'G'
8 'H'
9 'I'
10 'J'
```

Then I apply a query like this `SELECT * FROM table WHERE id IN (1, 10) FOR UPDATE;` I want to know what will happen after this. I remember once I read it from a blog this will lock **all the 10 rows**. But I can't repeat this. Does this problem actually exist? Or it is only I misremembered.

Comment: As usual, a simple look into the manual helps: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking.html And an advice, don't rely on bloggers. Some of them publish not really deeply researched topics, just to gain some fame (I guess). I've discovered mistakes or outdated information relatively often in blogs. The manual on the other hand is rarely wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most DBMS default isolation level is **read committed**,
so without you taking counter-measures you have the following issues:

- Non repeteable reads
  **and as a consequence:**

  - Lost update
  - read skew
  - write skew
  - phantom reads

The phantom **reads phenomenon** is what you are worried about in this case,
it implies that if you, for instance, use the exact same where clause in an update statement later on during your transaction, you could affect more/less or a completely different set of rows.

Answer (score 0):

I have read the manual helps:http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-locking.html

given by fancyPants, then I am sure that what I did would not lock a range of rows. Only the selected row would be locked. Now I think the blog I read before is wrong.

Thank you.